# Why didn't Joshua take Prisoners When conquering Israel?

Tags: death, army-military-war, joshua--book-of

Why didn't Joshua take prisoners when conquering Israel? In [Joshua chapter 10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0610.htm) it lists a number of nations that they conquer and kill. In verse 35 it states:

> [they] destroyed every soul that was in [Eglon] it that day (Artscroll)

Why was it required to kill everyone though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may put your mind at ease to know a war was never waged against any nation until an opportunity for a peaceful outcome was offered.

See Rambam here http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188350/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-6.htm

Here's a direct quote in Hebrew.

הלכות מלכים ומלחמותיהם- פרק
 ששי
א אין עושין מלחמה עם אדם בעולם עד שקוראין לו שלום אחד מלחמת הרשות ואחד מלחמת מצוה. שנאמר {כי תקרב אל עיר להלחם עליה וקראת אליה לשלום}. אם השלימו וקבלו שבע מצות שנצטוו בני נח עליהן אין הורגין מהן נשמה והרי הן למס. שנאמר {יהיו לך למס ועבדוך}. קבלו עליהן המס ולא קבלו העבדות או שקבלו העבדות ולא קבלו המס. אין שומעין להם עד שיקבלו שניהם. והעבדות שיקבלו הוא שיהיו נבזים ושפלים למטה ולא ירימו ראש בישראל אלא יהיו כבושים תחת ידם. ולא יתמנו על ישראל לשום דבר שבעולם. והמס שיקבלו שיהיו מוכנים לעבודת המלך בגופם וממונם. כגון בנין החומות. וחוזק המצודות. ובנין ארמון המלך וכיוצא בו. שנאמר {וזה דבר המס אשר העלה המלך שלמה לבנות את בית ה' ואת ביתו ואת המלוא ואת חומת ירושלים ואת כל ערי המסכנות אשר היו לשלמה. כל העם הנותר מן האמורי ויעלם שלמה למס עובד עד היום הזה ומבני ישראל לא נתן שלמה עבד כי הם אנשי המלחמה ועבדיו ושריו ושלישיו ושרי רכבו ופרשיו}: 
ב ויש למלך להתנות עמהם שיקח חצי ממונם או הקרקעות. ויניח כל המטלטלין או המטלטלים ויניח הקרקעות כפי מה שיתנה:
ג ואסור לשקר בבריתם ולכזב להם אחר שהשלימו וקבלו שבע מצות: 
ד ואם לא השלימו או שהשלימו ולא קבלו שבע מצות. עושין עמהם מלחמה והורגין כל הזכרים הגדולים. ובוזזין כל ממונם וטפם. ואין הורגין אשה ולא קטן שנאמר {והנשים והטף} זה טף של זכרים. במה דברים אמורים במלחמת הרשות שהוא עם שאר האומות. אבל שבעה עממין ועמלק שלא השלימו אין מניחין מהם נשמה שנאמר {כן תעשה לכל} וגו' {רק מערי העמים לא תחיה כל נשמה}. וכן הוא אומר בעמלק {תמחה את זכר עמלק}.

Answer (score 1):

God wanted the Jews to not be influenced by the sins of those who occupied the land. At the end of the Book of Genesis, you read how Joseph went from slave, to prisoner, to second in command in Egypt. There are several examples where the leaders were influenced by Hebrew slaves...Nebuchadnezzar is a great example.

It is reasonable that a slave could influence his/her owner to follow their religion. it would be possible for slaves of the people of Canaan could influence the Hebrews to follow after false gods. The history of the books of Samuel, Kings, and Chronicles show a Jewish history of turning against God, to follow false gods, God's judgment, God showing grace by sending a deliver who turns the people back to Jehovah.

Answer (score 0):

Because keeping prisoners is very expensive resource wise. Also, this wasn't a war to steal loot or create a vassal, it was a war of supplantation- to come in and replace the cannanites. You can't keep them prisoner because they might regroup.